# Prolog: remove integers from list

Tags: recursion, prolog

I am trying to remove the integers from a list using recursion. I made this `remove_integers` predicate and can't figure out why it does not work. Obviously I am missing something very essential about Prolog.

```
remove_integers([], L, L).
remove_integers([H|T], A, L) :-
    \+ integer(H),
    remove_integers(T, [A|H], L).
```

I did a trace on this predicate and got the following:

```
[trace]  ?- remove_integers([foo, bar, 1, 2, foo], [], L).
   Call: (7) remove_integers([foo, bar, 1, 2, foo], [], _G8188) ? 
   Call: (8) integer(foo) ? 
   Fail: (8) integer(foo) ? 
   Redo: (7) remove_integers([foo, bar, 1, 2, foo], [], _G8188) ? 
   Call: (8) remove_integers([bar, 1, 2, foo], [[]|foo], _G8188) ? 
   Call: (9) integer(bar) ? 
   Fail: (9) integer(bar) ? 
   Redo: (8) remove_integers([bar, 1, 2, foo], [[]|foo], _G8188) ? 
   Call: (9) remove_integers([1, 2, foo], [[[]|foo]|bar], _G8188) ? 
   Call: (10) integer(1) ? 
   Exit: (10) integer(1) ? 
   Fail: (9) remove_integers([1, 2, foo], [[[]|foo]|bar], _G8188) ? 
   Fail: (8) remove_integers([bar, 1, 2, foo], [[]|foo], _G8188) ? 
   Fail: (7) remove_integers([foo, bar, 1, 2, foo], [], _G8188) ? 
false.
```

So besides the fact that the intermediary list looks weird `[[[]|foo]|bar]` I do not understand why at some point it starts removing the items that are already in the accumulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issues with the original solution are: (1) the case where `X` is an integer is not handled at all, and (2) your call, `remove_integers(T, [A|H], L).` uses an element `H` as a tail for a list, which isn't correct in this context. You probably meant, `remove_integers(T, [H|A], L)`.

Correcting the code you have would yield:

```
remove_integers([], L, L).
remove_integers([H|T], A, L) :-
    integer(H),
    remove_integers(T, A, L).
remove_integers([H|T], A, L) :-
    \+ integer(H),
    remove_integers(T, [H|A], L).
```

But why you are using an extra argument here is unclear. It looks like you're defining an auxiliary predicate, but didn't define a main one. Also, this approach leaves you with the remaining elements in reverse order:

```
| ?- remove_integers([a,b,c,3,4,d], [], L).

L = [d,c,b,a] ? ;

no
```

You can do this without an auxiliary predicate or a cut by considering the 3 cases: (1) the base case (empty list), (2) the case where the head of the current list in question is an integer, and (3) the case where the head of the current list is not an integer:

```
remove_integers([], []).
remove_integers([X|T], R) :-
    integer(X),
    remove_integers(T, R).
remove_integers([X|T], [X|R]) :-
    \+ integer(X),
    remove_integers(T, R).

| ?- remove_integers([a,b,c,3,4,d], L).

L = [a,b,c,d] ? ;

no

| ?-
```

You can also use a Prolog "if-then-else" construct:

```
remove_integers([], []).
remove_integers([X|T], R) :-
    (   integer(X)
    ->  R = R1
    ;   R = [X|R1]
    ),
    remove_integers(T, R1).
```

Comment: This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. Thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 0):

always our problem is **CUT!**

```
remove_integers([],[]).
remove_integers([X|Xs],[X|Ys]) :-
        \+integer(X),!,
        remove_integers(Xs,Ys).
remove_integers([_|Xs],Ys) :-
        remove_integers(Xs,Ys).
```

**test :**

```
| ?- remove_integers([a,b,c,dfg,1,5,m,8,a],L).
L = [a,b,c,dfg,m,a] ? ;
no
```

Comment: thanks. can you explain a little how you came up with the answer? I am learning prolog and I am interested in how one comes to this routines more than the code itself.

Comment: @skamsie   I'm new to prolog and  this site help me a lot to learn it

Comment: I would not recommend going down the dark path of jumping to using a cut to solve a Prolog logic issue. Cuts can unnecessarily prune out valid solutions for otherwise more general predicates and shouldn't be used except when very specifically required.

Comment: Funnily enough, you use two cuts in 6 lines of code and yet you have a dangling choice point :) (hint: don't use cuts unless you actually need them -- see the solution by @lurker

Comment: @Boris,  can you explain the  problem without critical sense, I think this is much better than you feel the novices are frustrated

Comment: I am not sure what it is that you are trying to say, due to grammar problems. If you feel I was too critical in my comment: no, I wasn't. It was a simple observation based on facts. As it stands, your answer is subpar. Please read the answer by @lurker and compare it to yours to improve. Being a novice is not bad at all, but interpreting advice as criticism might be problematic.

Comment: @Boris, after all, it does not matter :), also I think my predicate it's correctly work , but what I do not understand; the problem is it in this line `\+integer(X),!` !

Comment: The problem is that you claim boldly that the **CUT** is both the problem and the solution, but in fact you don't need cuts at all, and they are better left out. You didn't even manage to get rid of the (unnecessary) choice point at the end by using cuts. Again, if you want to learn, read the other answer. Just my opinion.

Comment: Here is another test: `remove_integers([1,2,3],[]).` incorrectly succeeds, since 1, 2, and also 3 are integers.

Comment: it correctly delete all of integers that logically gives []